# jQuery for BlackBerry 10, background color

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, blackberry, blackberry-10

In my project for BB I'm including jQuery files:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BlackBerry-JQM-all-1.0.0.min.css" />
    <script src="BlackBerry-JQM-all-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

It seems to be OK, but now I want to change default white background color to for ex. black.

I tried to edit "BlackBerry-JQM-all.min.css" and add `background-color` there, but without success.

**Update**:

Found it!

In .css file, in ".ui-overlay-c {} "

Comment: Are you making a web app(Webworks) or mobile web? Why don't you use bbUI?

Comment: Webworks. I've seen an example with JQuerty for BB, so I started like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom CSS file and set `<body>` to black.

```
body {background-color:#000000;}
```

Comment: Included css file `  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> ` with your code, but it doesn't work for me. Still white.

Comment: Did you test it on Chrome or bb ripple? It can help you find out which CSS rule set it to White.

Comment: I have Ripple extension installed for Chrome, so to see my project I'm calling localhost/myProject in Chrome address bar.

Comment: There is a button called start emulator in the Ripple dropdown. You need to start it first. It's a node.js server.

Comment: Also, just for quick fix, would you assign and id to you body, and use this ID in CSS. If it still doesn't work, put a <div> inside your body and apply to CSS, and if it still doesn't work put style="background-color=#000000;" to your <body>, just for testing.